# How do I create a dummy variable by firm ID in a quarterly Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, dummy-variable

I have essentially 3 related questions regarding the creation of Dummies in a quarterly pandas DataFrame I am working with.
The first one is: How can I create a 'Dummy" variable that will set 1 for the last four quarters for each Firm ID? I would like to produce the same result as below:

```
Firm    Quarter     Dummy
A       2017-03-31  1
A       2016-12-31  1
A       2016-09-30  1
A       2016-06-30  1
A       2016-03-31  0
A       2015-12-31  0
A       2015-09-30  0
A       2015-06-30  0
A       2015-03-31  0
B       2009-06-30  1
B       2009-03-31  1
B       2008-12-31  1
B       2008-09-30  1
B       2008-06-30  0
B       2008-03-31  0
B       2007-12-31  0
B       2007-09-30  0
B       2007-06-30  0
.
.
.
Z       .           .
Z       .           .
Z       .           .
```

My second question is: how to create a 'Dummy' variable that sets 1 for the four quarters, one year after the last quarter (given different dates of the last quater for each firm)? as in the DataFrame below:

```
Firm    Quarter     Dummy
A       2017-03-31  0
A       2016-12-31  0
A       2016-09-30  0
A       2016-06-30  0
A       2016-03-31  1
A       2015-12-31  1
A       2015-09-30  1
A       2015-06-30  1
A       2015-03-31  0
B       2009-06-30  0
B       2009-03-31  0
B       2008-12-31  0
B       2008-09-30  0
B       2008-06-30  1
B       2008-03-31  1
B       2007-12-31  1
B       2007-09-30  1
B       2007-06-30  0
.
.
.
Z       .           .
Z       .           .
Z       .           .
```

And finally, regarding the previous table, how do I get rid of the first four quarters (Dummy = 0) before the first Dummy = 1, and keep the quarters where dummy = 0 AFTER the last Dummy = 1 for each firm ID?, to get a final DataFrame as follows:

```
Firm    Quarter     Dummy
A       2016-03-31  1
A       2015-12-31  1
A       2015-09-30  1
A       2015-06-30  1
A       2015-03-31  0
B       2008-06-30  1
B       2008-03-31  1
B       2007-12-31  1
B       2007-09-30  1
B       2007-06-30  0
.
.
.
Z       .           .
Z       .           .
Z       .           .
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Your wondering is rather confusing. Do you expect the last 5 quarters for each firm with the last one having `Dummy = 0` and the other 4 with `Dummy = 1`? Or do you expect 3 different results?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thanks for pointing it out. I expect 2 results. The first question is independent of the last 2 questions. For the first question, I only want to create a dummy variable that will set 1 for the last four quarters (the most recent quarters) and zero for the rest. This is it for the first question. The resulting DataFrame is the desired result. Then, the second question is divided into two steps, where the last table would be the final result. I hope this time I explained it better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each firm, if we number the last quarter as 1, the second last as 2, and so on, then your problem is just a filtering game:

- All quarters 1 - 4 are assigned `Dummy = 1`. The rest is 0
- All quarters 5 - 8 are assigned `Dummy = 1`. The rest is 0. And only take quarters 5 - 9.

Code:

```
s = df.sort_values('Quarter', ascending=False).groupby('Firm').cumcount().add(1).sort_index()

result1 = df.assign(Dummy=np.where(s.between(1, 4), 1, 0))
result2 = df.assign(Dummy=np.where(s.between(5, 8), 1, 0))[s.between(5, 9)]
```